# Combine Two Dataframes with a Function

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

```
head(CR1)
   Subject HourNominal Concentration Cohort    FS    EF   VTI deltaFS deltaEF deltaVTI
1  005-010        0.00            NA      1 30.87 65.48 21.59       0       0        0
2  005-010        0.25         31.00      1 31.82 64.86  0.00       3      -1     -100
4  005-010        1.00          9.69      1 26.13 69.11  0.00     -15       6     -100
7  005-010        3.00          3.26      1 29.89 60.99 23.49      -3      -7        9
12 005-010       24.00          1.52      1 29.67 57.18 22.17      -4     -13        3
13 005-010       48.00          1.23      1 35.41 56.70 20.85      15     -13       -3
```

I want to use this function

```
organizeR = function(x, y) {

  g1 = aggregate(y[,x], by=list(y[,'HourNominal']), FUN=mean)
  g1 = setNames(g1, c('HourNominal', 'Function'))
  g2 = aggregate(y[,x], by=list(y[,'HourNominal']), FUN=sd)
  g2 = setNames(g2, c('HourNominal', 'SD'))
  g1[,'SD'] = g2$SD
  g1$top = g1$Concentration + g1$SD
  g1$bottom = g1$Concentration - g1$SD

  return(g1)
}
```

- Find the mean for each timepoint
- Find the Standard Deviation for each timepoint
- Put the two dataframes together
- Create columns which tell the mean - SD and mean + SD

> CRA1 = organizeR('FS', CR1)
>
> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "top", value = numeric(0)) :
>   replacement has 0 rows, data has 9

Why does the replacement have 0 rows?  This works whenever I do it outside of the custom function, so it should work in the function.

```
aggregate(CR1[,'FS'], by=list(CR1[,'HourNominal']), FUN=mean)
  Group.1        x
1    0.00 32.40375
2    0.25 31.52125
3    1.00 34.24000
4    3.00 32.48750
5   24.00 35.20375
6   48.00 34.80375
7   96.00 36.15500
8  216.00 35.76571
9  648.00 33.53000
aggregate(CR1[,'FS'], by=list(CR1[,'HourNominal']), FUN=sd)
  Group.1        x
1    0.00 3.810534
2    0.25 4.993211
3    1.00 6.061989
4    3.00 4.105341
5   24.00 6.814786
6   48.00 4.587701
7   96.00 6.314292
8  216.00 4.434794
9  648.00 2.968451
```

Comment: I'm guessing the replacement has zero rows because `g1` has no `$Concentration`... Anyway, `aggregate` is not very suitable for an intermediate step in a function in my experience. I'd suggest dplyr or data.table for anything beyond the most simple by-group stuff.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed that one there.  I don't know why R can't print an error message stating that a certain column doesn't exist >:(

Comment: Yeah, I agree. There are other ways to get it, like `g1[["Concentration"]]` but they will also fail silently... I'm not sure a way to do it that is more debug-friendly.

Comment: A more debug friendly way is to use `g1[,"Concentration"]`, which will throw the error "Unidentified columns selected" if the column doesn't exist.